# How to replace an unsafe function with a safe one in Intel PinTool？

Tags: c++, intel-pin

How to develop an unsafe function replacement plugin based on Intel PIN framework?
For instance, replace `strcpy` with `strcpy_s`. I tried `RTN_FindByName(img,"strcpy")` to find strcpy and used `PIN_UndecorateSymbolName`, however, it seemed not work, I can't find `strcpy` to replace.

Comment: How do you plan to get the value for dstsz parameter?

Comment: Anyway please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so you can get help